# Creating a simple ToDo App using AngularJS showing $controller:ctrlreg error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a To-Do app using AngularJS, but it is saying an error which is related to

> Error: $controller:ctrlreg,

the directed link says:

> A controller with this name is not registered.

Below is my code with the script.

```js
angular.module('todoApp', [])
  .controller('todoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [];
    $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.tasks.push($scope.title);
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<br>
<div ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="todoController"><br>
  <input ng-model="title"><button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    <br><li ng-repeat="t in tasks">{{t}}</li>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: I have create a snippet for you, see if you can reproduce the issue

Comment: This is working, but it is not working when I run it in my browser. Why?

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Comment: No, I have one more function which returns the same text, when a  user enters a text in the text-field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code running fine,

```js
angular.module('todoApp', [])
    .controller('todoController', function($scope){
        $scope.tasks = [];
        $scope.add = function() {
            $scope.tasks.push($scope.title);
            $scope.title = ''
        }
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp" >

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

<div ng-controller="todoController">
    <input ng-model="title"><button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    <li ng-repeat="t in tasks">{{t}}</li>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Alright, so the thing is, I have put <html ng-app> on top because I have one more function which returns the same text entered in a text field, just to say a person's name. If I remove the ng-app from the html tag, the above code works perfect. But my other function does not work.

Comment: @VishalLimbachiya have you added two times ng-app directive in your app, one at div and one at html tag?

Comment: Yes I have used it 2 times.

Comment: please post me your full html

Comment: <html ng-app>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourname" placeholder="Enter your name: ">
  <hr>
  <h1> Hello! {{yourname}}!</h1>
 </div>
<div id="todoApp" ><br>
<div ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="todoController">
<input ng-model="title"><button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
<li ng-repeat="t in tasks">{{t}}</li>

Comment: just remove the ng-app="todoApp" from div tag and add directly to html tag

Answer (score 1):

check this out : [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/job27javyFFKHPXHE82d?p=preview)

**index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="title"><button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    <br><li ng-repeat="t in tasks">{{t}}</li>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tasks = [];
    $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.tasks.push($scope.title);
    }
});
```